# Who first proved Fermat's Last Theorem for polynomials and when?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, math-history

Who first proved Fermat's Last Theorem for polynomials and when?  I have a proof using the Mason-Stothers Theroem, but the result is much older.  Does anyone know the original proof or prover?  Or at least an older proof (or prover) that doesn't use a result from the 1980's?

That is,
$$
x(t)^n + y(t)^n = z(t)^n
$$
has no solutions for $n \geq 3$ where $x(t), y(t)$ and $z(t)$ are non-constant relatively prime polynomials with complex (or even just integer) coefficients.

Comment: I have discovered a truly marvelous demonstration of this proposition, but the comment field is too short.

Comment: It goes back to the 19th century. See references on the page http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/98/flt_poly, especially the last chapter of Ribenboim's 13 Lectures on Fermat's Last Theorem.